# When can you call IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType?

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation

If I have an active asynchronous IMFSourceReader when is it safe to call SetCurrentMediaType() on it?

Originally I tried IMFSourceReaderCallback::OnReadSample() and IMFSourceReaderCallback::OnFlush() with object access guarded by a critical section but I get errors relating to there being pending samples or an io completion port error.

It's really not made clear what is safe to call within IMFSourceReaderCallback functions that get called from the media foundation worker threads.

Do I have to completely flush/drain the pipeline from outside of the callback function threads, then signal from the callback thread OnFlush() to threads outside of the callback call stack (make sure no further sample reads are queued) that is then safe to change the media format with SetCurrentMediaType()?

Do I have to go even further and destroy the SourceReader, and then start again to recreate and then set the media format?

Comment: It's a good question, I suppose the expected behavior is that it is allowed to do `SetCurrentMediaType` from `OnFlush`. However reuse of reader and source with changed media type slips away from baseline functionality so there might be issues, including related to underlying media source rather than source reader. Hard to tell what exactly is wrong with doing this from `OnFlush` without debugging but it makes sense to create a backup code path with dropping reader and re-creating it from fresh, possibly with reuse of active media source.

Comment: A remark in the docs for OnFlush notes an Win7 bug (which I am on the latest update of).  Where OnFlush is called before the flush operation completes and then gives a dead link for further details (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979567).  I am not sure if I am hitting that but whatever thread safe scheme I come up with to change the media format when there are no pending reads (from a logitech webcamera) sporadically gives me an ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE in the OnReadSample() callback after the media format appears to have been changed without error and I request a new sample to be read.

Comment: I will try completely recreating the source reader with the new media format as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as soon as you have set the media format it is unsafe to change it after the source reader becomes active.  So you have to destroy the source reader and recreate it.

But then destroying the async source reader reliably without a hanging on Win7 is another question...

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem, I got the format to properly change in async mode by:

1. When a format change request is received set a flag
2. In the next OnReadSample callback, read the flag and do NOT call ReadSample
3. After OnReadSample completes, the reader is now ready to have the format changed

This worked for me, granted I have only tested on a single camera